# Synapse CETAS from parquet file with columns definition is failing

Tags: azure-data-factory, parquet, azure-synapse, external-tables

In a Synapse pipeline, I'm trying to use a CETAS script activity from a parquet file that I generate before (from an Azure SQL database).
The source database has some tables containing LOB columns (xml type), so the default varchar(8000) type isn't sufficient for some values.
I tried to define the columns and types:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myTable ([column1] int, [column2] varchar(MAX))
WITH (
        LOCATION = 'myLocation',
        DATA_SOURCE = mySource,
        FILE_FORMAT = Parquet
) 
AS
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'myParquetFile.parquet',
    FORMAT='PARQUET') AS f;
```

My actual table has 24 columns (not just 2 as in the above script), but I get this message when running the script:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2011",
    "message": "Different number of columns in CREATE TABLE or CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE and SELECT query.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "myScriptName",
    "details": []
}
```

When checking with a parquet file viewer, it does contain 24 columns, exactly as the column definition I pass in the CETAS script.
Is there a kind of "hidden" column in a parquet file? Should I replace the "SELECT *" by the exact list of the 24 columns?

thanks for your help!

Comment: "Should I replace the "SELECT *" by the exact list of the 24 columns?" isn't working, I just tried. Same error.

Comment: Did you tried the same in normal script? Is that resulting same error as script activity?

Comment: thanks for your reply! Yes, I tried this as a standalone script activity, and I get the same result (but I'm using the same parquet file that was generated via the previous copy activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tweaked the source parquet file (step before the external table creation). The columns with LOB were containing xml code, that I did not necessarily require. I truncated them to remain within the 8000 chars limit (and use the CETAS statement without having to define the columns schemas)
In the copy activity, I used the below statement within the SELECT of the source:
LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[myColumnToTruncate]),8000) AS [myColumnToTruncate]
This is not perfect as the data is not kept entirely, but this fitted my requirement.
Thanks to @RakeshGovindula and @Bhavani for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to replicate the issue with the script below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myTable ([EMPLOYEE_ID] int, [FIRST_NAME] varchar(MAX))
WITH (
        LOCATION = '<location>',
        DATA_SOURCE = '<dataSource>',
        FILE_FORMAT = <fileFormat>
) 
AS
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'employees.parquet',
    FORMAT='PARQUET') AS f;
```

I got a similar error:

[image]

I used the following script to resolve the issue:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.emp (
    [EMPLOYEE_ID] int,
    [FIRST_NAME] varchar(MAX)
)
WITH (
    LOCATION = '<location>',
    DATA_SOURCE = <dataSource>,
    FILE_FORMAT = <fileFormat>
)
```

The script activity ran successfully without any errors:

[image]

Created External table:

[image]

If you want to get all columns from the source, you can use the code below:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK '<filePath>',
    FORMAT='PARQUET'
) AS [dbo.employee];
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhavani for your time spent on this! If I understand, you only keep the part of the script that creates the external table, and remove the "AS SELECT *" part. What I don't get, is that I cannot query the table after its creation (in your case "dbo.employees1"): "External table 'myTable' is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another process." The LOCATION parameter is supposed to contain the parquet files generated while using the CETAS statement, but it is not existing at all, as the SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (...) is not used while creating the table.